# Copy Code/Text From GitHub Doesn't Retain Tabs

Tags: github

If I copy code or text from a file in my GitHub repository, and copy it to any Windows application (say, Notepad for arguments sake), it doesn't retain the tabs.

Is there any workaround to this?  What is the cause?

**Edit**: I copy and paste with the traditional **Ctrl-C** and **Ctrl-V** combination or any other variation of the same operation.

Comment: How do you copy? From the browser, selecting text and using the clipboard? From the "raw" view or the formatted view?

Comment: I copy with normal copy and paste (see edit).  What do you mean, "raw" view or "formatted" view?

Comment: formatted: https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/blob/6417cf4d1ba1da314b53901214b262267b5fcdc4/LICENSE   raw: https://raw.github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/6417cf4d1ba1da314b53901214b262267b5fcdc4/LICENSE

Comment: Ah, nice!  Raw works perfectly.  If you put that as an answer (which it is) then I'll mark it and upvote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are copying from the pretty-printed HTML version of the file, this may mess up the original formatting a little.

As a workaround, switch to the "Raw" tab (or just download the file).